# Multiple results from different date range inside one Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select

So, I have the following query

```sql
SELECT pn.no,
       pn.nome,
       SUM(qtt)
FROM pn,
     st
WHERE fdata > '2021-01-01'
  AND fdata < '2021-03-01'
  AND pn.ref = st.ref
  AND st.forref LIKE '%product%'
GROUP BY pn.no,
         pn.nome;
```

That returns me the results between the 01/01/2021 and 01/03/2021.

What I need to do is compare this with the same period this year.

How can I get the results for both periods in one select?

Comment: You can query it for 2021 and 2022 in two selects, then combine the two selects via join: `select * from (SELECT_2021) o left join (SELECT_2022) n where n.no = o.no and n.nome = o.nome`.

Comment: FYI, it's **2022**, the ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax has been around for **30 years**; why have you not adopted it yet? [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0):

you can FULL OUTER JOIN 2022 to the subquery of 2021 on product number

So you can get all possible products

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(p1.no,p2.no),
    COALESCE (p1.nome,p2.nome),
    CASE
        WHEN COALESCE (sum_qt1,0) > COALESCE (sum_qt2,0) THEN 'more'
        WHEN COALESCE (sum_qt1,0) < COALESCE (sum_qt2,0) THEN 'less'
        ELSE 'equal'
    END
FROM
    (SELECT 
        pn.no, pn.nome, SUM(qtt) sum_qt2
    FROM
        pn JOIN  st ON pn.ref = st.ref
    WHERE
        fdata > '2022-01-01'
            AND fdata < '2022-03-01'            
            AND st.forref LIKE '%product%'
    GROUP BY pn.no , pn.nome) p1
        FULL OUTER  JOIN
    (SELECT 
        pn.no, pn.nome, SUM(qtt) sum_qt1
    FROM
        pn JOIN st ON pn.ref = st.ref
    WHERE
        fdata > '2021-01-01'
            AND fdata < '2021-03-01'
            AND st.forref LIKE '%product%'
    GROUP BY pn.no , pn.nome) p2 ON p1.no = p2.no
```

Comment: However unlikely it might be, you should use a full outer join since there is no guarantee that rows exist for either period. That is more likely to happen when the period is much smaller.

Comment: @nbk maybe I didn't explain myself correctly.

The code I posted gives a series of results related to the period between 01/01/2021 and 01/03/2021. What I need to do is to get the results from the sam period but from this year (01/01/2022 and 01/03/2022) and, compare them. The code you posted does not do that. I need the actual values and not just the indication if it's more or less.

Comment: the code compares the quantity of two period '2021-01-01' -  '2021-03-01' to that of '2022-01-01' - '2022-03-01' or every product. you ask how can i do it and this makes **exactly** that. try it. Without specifying what comparing means exactly, i added my own case when for comparing so that you can understand the code better.